# HTC Sense live wallpaper picker

Tags: htc-sense, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

Is there a way to set the image preview for the HTC Sense 4+ live wallpaper chooser?  Currently, it just scales my thumbnail to a much larger size, which makes it look pretty bad.

Here is an image of what I am referring to:

[image]

See how it just scaled?  I am just wondering if there is a way to set the image that is used.  I have noticed HTC live wallpapers look great, but I don't know if they have that image in their system files or in the actual apk.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a live wallpaper that you're writing yourself? It sounds like that's the case, which would likely be better suited for [SO] (and has been discussed some [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514418/how-to-set-the-android-live-wallpaper-icon-aka-thumbnail))

Comment: it's funny you said  that, I found the same question on stackoverflow but it was closed because it was off topic or something and they directed the person to come here and ask.  Thanks though I emailed HTC and they answered.

Answer (score 1):

I emailed  HTC  and this was there response in case anyone is interested.

"I understand you have a question about Live Wallpapers for your Android device. I would be more than happy to assist you with this device feature inquiry. You mention that you would like to know whether a developer would have access to the area where you choose the wallpaper or scene for the Home screen of your phone? This question would be difficult to answer since this might require "rooting" or unlocking the boot loader of your phone possibly."

so as vague as it is,  it seems like  they are system files used for HTC  live wallpaper previews.  I guess a scaled thumbnail is as good as it gets.